# Affine warp of rectangle

Tags: graphics, computer-vision, interpolation

I need to warp imaginary rectangle lying on the image.
So I think I need:

1. Detect which pixels of images belong to rectangle (something like rasterization?).
2. Do warp of pixels and somehow do interpolation in rectangle (I don't know how) between pixels.
3. How to deal with border pixels of belonging to different rectangles?
   [image]

Generally I trying to do something like this 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For warping the images, the following procedure can be applied.

Assuming that you have the displacements of each of the points on the lattice, you need to do a B-Spline interpolation(based on the displacements of the neighboring lattice points) to deform the source image.

For obtaining the optimal displacement of each lattice point, you can use a label set corresponding to the displacement of the lattice point in x-y direction and compute SSD between patches in the source and the target image for different labels. For a smooth solution, a regularization prior needs to be added, so that neighboring points on the lattice have a similar displacement. This joint optimization problem can be solved using MRFs.